# How to store or save and retrieve multiple remote images locally

Tags: android, local-storage

I am looking for a solution in Android to store remote images (URLs retrieved from webservices) into the local (SDcard or Sqlite db or cache) so the images can be displayed in offline-mode too.
because I want to display each time a picture during a call.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Plenty. What keywords did you use when googling?

Comment: store remote images locally in SDcard or sqlite db

Comment: The magic word is "cache", and don't forgot to include "android." Good luck! There are several solutions out there. Unfortunately, asking for libraries and such is off-topic here.

Comment: thanks, "There are several solutions out there." like what?

Comment: Sorry, you need to show a bit of effort here. I'm not going to google for you and cut&paste the results, like the answerer below did.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these steps (for only one image retrieval at a time):

1. Retrieve image as Bitmap from URL.
2. Convert Bitmap into byte array.
3. Store byte array into blob field of SQLite DB Table.
4. Get blob from SQLite DB table.
5. Convert blob to byte array.
6. Convert byte array into Bitmap.
7. Finally, set Bitmap as image onto ImageMap of the Activity.

public class ImageStoreAndRetrievalActivity extends Activity {

```
private ImageView imageView;
private DatabaseHandler dbHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_store);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());       
    new MyThread("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(dbHandler.getBitmap(1));  // here 1 is id for the image into tbl_blob table in SQLite DB.
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private String url;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;
    private Thread th;
    public MyThread(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        try {
            th.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        URL fileUrl = null;  

        try {  
            fileUrl = new URL(url);  
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) fileUrl.openConnection();  
            conn.setConnectTimeout(0);  
            conn.setDoInput(true);  
            conn.connect();  
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();  
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  
            is.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }   
        dbHandler.insertBitmap(bitmap);
        Log.i("URL", url);
    }

}
```

}

```
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "blobdb";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String CREATE_BLOB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_blob " + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, img BLOB NOT NULL, description TEXT NULL)";
```

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private Context context;

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // create all tables in 'btlocdb'
    createTables(db);
}

/** create all tables in 'btlocdb'.
 * @param db
 */
public void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {       
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BLOB_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Consts.Table.DATABASE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    //onCreate(db);
}

public void insertBitmap(Bitmap bm) 
{

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    byte[] buffer=out.toByteArray();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    // Starts the transaction.
    db.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues values;        
    try 
    {
        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("img", buffer); 
        values.put("description", "This is a description"); 
        // Inserting Row
        long i = db.insert("tbl_blob", null, values);
        Log.i("Insert", i + "");
        // Insert or update data into database successfully.
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();                                    
    }       
    catch (SQLiteException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                      
    finally
    {
        db.endTransaction(); // Ending the transaction.
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(int id){
    Bitmap bm = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Starts the transaction.
    db.beginTransaction();
    try 
    {                       
        String selectQuery = "select * from tbl_blob where id = " + id;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        Log.i("Cursor", cursor.getCount() + "");        
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {                        
                    byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("img"));
                    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }               
        }                   
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();  
    }       
    catch (SQLiteException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                      
    finally
    {
        db.endTransaction(); // Ending the transaction.
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
    return bm;      
}
```

}

Hope this will help you!!!
Let me know if you have any query regarding this issue. Thanks..